# Options to restart services on multiple Azure VMs

Tags: powershell, azure, runbook

We currently have multiple Azure VMs all on the same virtual network. We would like to run a script, which, in case of failure restarts the services on a VM, but we would want to run that script on all vms at the same time (in parallel).

I have currently tried with runbook which works but it is not an option since it takes about 5 minutes to complete.

Another option seems to be with Invoke-Command but that would mean opening some ports (I am not sure if the endpoint needs to be opened since the machines are on the same virtual network) which is not very convenient.

Does someone has another idea maybe?

Comment: just create a long running task on each vm to monitor the service and restart it?

Comment: The problem is that we sometimes want to restart the service on all machines at once at will, not meaning that the service is stopped, so it needs to be done manually. Or stop it in case 3rd party fails for example. And we want to do it from one machine which connects to all others and stops the services for example

Comment: well, I'd go for PS remoting. You can use one of the VM's and initiate a command from one of the VM's (so it doesn't leave Azure). Also, you could just create an endpoint for your service, which you could query to restart a service.

Comment: Have you thought about using Desired State Configuration (DSC)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/serviceresource?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 DSC will check on a periodic (30 mins by default) basis if the service is on or not. If it is off, it will try and start it again.

Comment: @TimHaintz Sometimes we want to stop the services as I have said above. That doesn't mean the service is already stopped. They might be working just fine but something else might have failed.